# How can I create a Query for find the percentage of data (based on the value for each field)?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table **Toxicity**, which show the side effect of drug for several patients, as shown below:

The value in the columns:Nausea, Vomit, and Skin refers to the drug toxicity. There are 4 values of severity: 0,1,2,3

```
|-----|---------------|--------|-------|------| 
| ID  | Regime Course | Nausea | Vomit | Skin | 
| 1   | Regime A      | 1      | 2     | 1    | 
| 2   | Regime A      | 1      | 1     | 1    | 
| 3   | Regime A      | 2      | 3     | 2    | 
| 4   | Regime A      | 0      | 0     | 2    | 
| 5   | Regime B      | 3      | 0     | 3    | 
| 6   | Regime B      | 3      | 3     | 3    | 
| 7   | Regime B      | 1      | 3     | 1    | 
| 8   | Regime B      | 2      | 2     | 0    | 
| 9   | Regime A      | 3      | 2     | 0    | 
| 10  | Regime A      | 3      | 2     | 0    | 
| 11  | Regime A      | 0      | 1     | 1    | 
| 12  | Regime A      | 0      | 1     | 1    | 
| 13  | Regime B      | 1      | 1     | 2    | 
| 14  | Regime B      | 2      | 0     | 0    | 
| 15  | Regime B      | 1      | 0     | 2    | 
| 16  | Regime B      | 0      | 0     | 0    | 
|-----|---------------|--------|-------|------|
```

What query should I use so that I could get the percentage of all side effects (e.g. Nausea=1,Nausea=2,Skin=0, Skin=2) for both Regime?

Example of Result:

```
Regime A |  Nausea:0  | 0.375
Regime A |  Nausea:1  | 0.25
Regime A |  Nausea:2  | 0.125
Regime A |  Nausea:3  | 0.25
Regime B |  Nausea:0  | 0.125
Regime B |  Nausea:1  | 0.375
Regime B |  Nausea:2  | 0.25
Regime B |  Nausea:3  | 0.25
...
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to get ratios for nausea:

```
select
  regime,
  nausea,
  regime_nausea_count / (1.0*regime_count) as nausea_ratio
from 
  (
    select
      regime,
      nausea,
      count(*) as regime_nausea_count
    from
      Toxicity
    group by regime, nausea
   ),
 (
    select
      regime,
      count(*) as regime_count
    from
      Toxicity
    group by regime
  ) using (regime);
```

Obviously, you could replace nausea with another column to get the corresponding statistics.